# Was Mary from the tribe of Aaron?

Tags: quran

I have a question. Since in Quran Mary is called sister of Aaron which scholars interpret that she was from his tribe. Well I have checked her father who is Imran in Quran genealogies in various interpretations of Quran(Zamakhshari, Qurtubi, Tabari and others as well) none of them suggest that he was from the same tribe as Aaron i.e. the tribe of Levi. Instead they trace back to Judah.
Doesn't this mean that Mary was from the tribe of Judah or other tribe? If this is the case is Quran wrong in claiming her sister of Aaron then?
Since we Muslims don't believe in biblical genealogies of Mary which too suggest that she was from Judah, that's why I had to check through Islamic sources.
Genealogies are as follows

(Zamakhshari)عيسى ابن مريم بنت عمران بن ماثان بن سليمان بن داود بن إيشا بن يهوذا بن يعقوب بن

إسحاق
عمران بن ياشم بن أمون بن ميشا بن حزقيا بن أحريق بن يوثم بن عزاريا بن أمصيا بن ياوش بن أجريهو بن يازم بن يهفاشاط بن إنشا بن أبيان بن رخيعم بن سليمان بن داود عليهما السلام(Ibn Kathir)

عمران بن ماثان بن العازار بن أبي يوذ بن يوزن بن زربابل بن ساليان بن يوحنا بن أوشيا بن أمون بن منشكن بن حازقا بن أخاز بن يوثام بن عوزيا بن يورام بن سافط بن ايشا بن راجعيم بن سليمان بن داود بن ايشي بن عوبد بن سلمون بن ياعز بن نحشون بن عمياد بن رام بن حصروم بن فارص بن يهوذا بن يعقوب عليه السلام(baidawi)

Comment: @UmH If Mary had been from the tribe of Levi then wouldn't have Imran's genealogy had traced back to the tribe of Levi? Since we believe in quran and islamic traditions which mention Mary's father as Imran.

Comment: Well there are lot of different genealogies suggested by early scholars but not any single of them trace back to the tribe of Levi.

Comment: And where do you think these genealogies come from? They are copied from the stories spread by the People of the Book and have no reliability and indeed contradict with each other and sometimes even with mathematics. We don't know of Mary's true genealogy, so it is possible that she was from the tribe of Levi as some Muslim and even non-Muslim scholars have claimed. This is already covered in the linked duplicate.

Comment: However there are also other explanations for the Quranic verse which have been recorded by the tafsirs, such as: (i) This Aaron was different from Prophet Aaron, and the name was re-used because people named their children after the names of past prophets and saints (a practice which occurs even today as you may find many people named Harun\Aaron even today). (ii) The word sister is used in a sense of similarity rather than kinship, like in verse [17:27](https://quran.com/17/27) which calls people 'brothers of satan'.  This too is covered in the linked duplicate.

Comment: "When I came to Najran, they (the Christians of Najran) asked me:  You read "Sister of Harun", (i.e. Mary), in the Qur'an, whereas Moses was born well before Jesus. When I came back to Allah's Messenger I asked him about that, and he said:  "The (people of the old age) used to give names (to their persons) after the names of Apostle and pious persons who had gone before them."(muslim). there are other reports that says she is attributed to the tribe of Thamim as well, so as @UmH has stated, i believe this question is in the vein of a duplicate.

Comment: Does it mean that scholars were contradicting themselves. On one hand they said Mary sister of Aaron is like saying brother of Tamim and on the other hand they themselve mentioned the genealogies which none of them suggest that she was from the tribe of Levi.

Comment: And referring to the link in duplicate couldn't it be possible that Mary's mother was from the Levi tribe and not his father. As suggested by other biblical scholars.